# How do I write a recursive function that makes the geometric progression in OCaml?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

In OCaml, for a geometric progression, I have to write a recursive function using constant values for the first term and the ratio.
I also have to write a function that also has these two parameters using let...in and an auxiliar function with one parameter.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#something like that ?
let rec u u0 q = function
   0 -> u0
  |n -> q * u u0 q (n-1)
;;
```

test :

```
# u 1 2 1;;
- : int = 2
# u 1 2 5;;
- : int = 32
```